# Best practice to handling exceptions of ef core in asp.net project?

Tags: exception, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

i use ef core 2.1 in asp.net core mvc project.i also use repository pattern to access database.

ISSUE:

i want show some exceptions(e.g foreign key constraint fails) with ajax  to user 
and other exceptions svae in log file of  my program.by applying DRY method to avoid use try....catch repeated blocks in my code

how can do it?
thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AOP](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-using-Interceptors/index.html) ( Aspect Oriented Programming ) or [custom middlewares](https://code-maze.com/global-error-handling-aspnetcore/) in asp.net core for cross-cutting concerns like exception handling and logging.